# Saving the toggle condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have written a code for the flip switch but the state always changes while refreshing the page:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code directly to SO, dont use screenshots.

Comment: Try [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: Php code will be not executed by browser. This file is served by apache/nginx ?

Comment: can we save the toggle state using cookies

Comment: yes you can)) 
but as I think it is faster to do with local storage

Comment: can you please help me to modify code because i am not good at web coding

Comment: @mika don't post image post real code

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5w9EoD

Comment: @Maivuye cokile https://codeshare.io/5w9EoD  here is the code

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are trying to replace the Ajax post request you have with something else.

My suggestion would be to use a cookie which will save some information locally for js to use.

Firstly, add [jQuery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js) & [jQuery Cookie](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js) to the top of your webpage like this (within the `<head>` tag):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Then, in your javascript file, do the following:

```
(function($) {
  // Grabs cookie and puts into a js variable.
  var toggled = $.cookie('toggled');

//  On click of checkbox, check if set/unset. Then set cookie to true/false.

  $('#switch').change(function()) {
      if($(this).is(':checked')) { // If set to true, set toggled to true.
        $.cookie('toggled', true, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
      } else { // Else, set to false.
        $.cookie('toggled', null, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
      }
  }

})(jQuery);
```

You'll need to then check the toggled cookie on refresh and add behaviour to check the box if toggled is true:

```
if(toggled == 'true') { //If cookie set to true...
 $('#switch').attr('checked','checked').flipswitch("refresh") // Flip the switch (Important for jquery mobile).
}
```

Please see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pf4cr5mu/3/) for a working example.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i am beginner can you please help me in detail.. Sorry for the trouble ... please understand my problem

Comment: @mika I've updated my answer and added a jsfiddle example with a working example.

Comment: @mika Added (I think)

Comment: kevin sir when i run that code in browser the toggle state is not saved it is reverting bzck to its orginal off condition when refreshing the page

Comment: @mika There seemed to be a few double quotes missing. I've deleted the php part but check again to see if working. You'll have to re-add the php again

Comment: sorry to trouble u sir.. still i am not getting.. please look at it

Comment: @mika Updated Link. See https://codeshare.io/5w9EoD && https://jsfiddle.net/pf4cr5mu/2/

Comment: @kelvin sir https://codeshare.io/a3yJgB the code is not working can you please tell me the mistake i have done

Comment: @mika I'm not sure. Is the jsfiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/pf4cr5mu/5/) works working on your end?

Comment: ya the code is working in jsfiddle but its not working in html page